# File is not accessing in java

Tags: java, linux, file, file-io, java-io

```
File file = new File("\\10.200.64.8\\home\\rbts\\IBST000826");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
```

is giving error , I have tried also as

```
File file = new File("file:\\10.200.64.8\\home\\rbts\\IBST000826");
```

and

```
File file = new File(new URI("file:////10.200.64.8/home/rbts/IBST000826"));
```

the file is on linux machine and i m accessing it on windows machine. Can any body give suggestion or solution.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \10.200.64.8\home\rbts\IBST000826 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sapphire.oracle.osb.hbl.isohandler.utils.ISO_MessageUtils.getFileContent(ISO_MessageUtils.java:350)
    at com.sapphire.oracle.osb.hbl.isohandler.utils.ISO_MessageUtils.main(ISO_MessageUtils.java:366)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
File file = new File("\\\\10.200.64.8\\home\\rbts\\IBST000826");
                    //^^^^
```

to ensure `\\` in file path.

Comment: @AhmedJunaid, that is not what I suggested.

Comment: can you please write here the same which u want to suggest me ihave tried also File file = new File("//ip//home//rbts//IBST000826");

Comment: @AhmedJunaid, I have in my answer !?

Comment: some where i have seen that to access file on linux machine it is required to authenticate from windows OS. I think thats the reason